# Regular expression on range

Tags: regex

Sorry for these silly Question but i couldn't find a clue on my own

I am a beginner at regexp language and  I  want someone help to find and replace the following value in content-range Http=Header

```
Content-Range: bytes x-xxxxx/xxxx
```

i want to find the `xxxx` value and replace it with `yyyyy` so the value will be

```
x-xxxxxx/yyyy
```

for example

`0-423423/7777777` to be `0-423423/9999999`

Can anyone help me in it

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

since you didn't provide details on implementing language, here are the regex and the replacement in PCRE-style

#### Regex

```
(\d+-\d+)/\d+
```

#### Replacement

```
$1/1234512345
```

where `1234512345` is your replacement-value (the number after the slash you want to change)